# Turn value from SQL into PHP

Tags: php, string

Let's say I have saved this kind of data (some text '.date(d).' some text) to SQL (with htmlspecialchars()). Now, if I restore htmlspecialchars, is there a way for me to have PHP fill in the date?

Basically I guess what I'm asking is, is there way to turn text into php string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always `eval()` a string, but the possible security implications of this are very grave, so I wouldn't recommend it.

If it's a particular expression, you can substitute it - say, @@date@@ would get string-replaced with an actual `date(d)` result.

Comment: This is actually a language file that I would like to move from PHP to MYSQL but I need it to be somewhat dynamic. Since no one would be able to add/edit the data that goes through eval(), would it be OK?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean executing a string as PHP code, you can use [eval()](http://uk.php.net/eval)

Comment: If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf

Answer (score 1):

[eval](http://se.php.net/eval)() evaluates a string as PHP code, but be careful - it can destroy all of your work (or some of it as well) if you're not sure what the string contains!